# How display list given range in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, slice

How do I write a function that displays a given range in a list in Haskell? Say that I have the function:

```hs
dispRange l x y
```

that when given values:

```hs
dispRange [1,2,4,5,6,7] 0 3
```

displays all the elements from position 0 to 3, thus the list returned would be:

```hs
[1,2,4,5]
```

Comment: What is not working with your approach?

Comment: I tried using conditionals in list comprehensions but I can't seem to find the correct way to do it for ranges.

Answer (score 6):

We can use a combination of [**`drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop) and [**`take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=take) for this:

For a range `i` to `j`, we first *drop* `i` elements, and then *take* `j-i+1` elements (since both indices are *inclusive*, we thus need to add one).

For example:

```
dispRange :: [a] -> Int -> Int -> [a]
dispRange l i j = take (j-i+1) (drop i l)
```

We can guard against negative numbers and `j` being less than `i` with:

```
dispRange :: [a] -> Int -> Int -> Maybe [a]
dispRange l i j | i < 0 || j < i = Nothing
                | otherwise = Just (take (j-i+1) (drop i l))
```

Comment: How do I add conditionals such that both indices cannot be negative and that the first index cannot be greater than the second and show the error message. I am just starting out in functional programming and the syntax is really confusing.

Comment: @RyanThompson: well the question is what you should do in that case, frequently in Haskell if the function is "non-total", one makes it total by rewriting the return type to `Maybe [a]`, or `Either String [a]` to specify that the computation can "fail".

Answer (score 2):

`dispRange` consumes a list: `l`, the start:`x` and the end:`y` of a range inclusively. It returns the elements within that range if the range is not negative.

```
import Data.List ((\\))

dispRange :: Eq a => [a] -> Int -> Int -> [a]
dispRange l x y  
  | x <= y = (\\) <$> take (y + 1) <*> take x $ l
  | otherwise = []
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a way that doesn't use built-in functions (for beginner's learning), you can break it into two stages:

1. Chop off the first *x* elements, recursively calling your function and changing the arguments as appropriate.
2. Return the next *y* elements, recursively calling your function and changing the arguments as appropriate.

Your code will look like this:

```hs
dispRange :: …
dispRange … … … = []
dispRange … … … = dispRange … … …
⋮  ⋮  ⋮  ⋮  ⋮  ⋮  ⋮  ⋮  ⋮  ⋮
dispRange … … … = dispRange … … …
```

So, the questions are:

- What are the types of the arguments and the value returned?
- What do the inputs of the base and recursive cases look like for stage one above?
- What do the inputs of the base and recursive cases look like for stage two above?

Now, you can write the type signature and the patterns on the left of the equal signs (remember that patterns above take priority over patterns below, so order them properly). Then, you can write the implementation of each case on the right of the equal sign.

---

If you have trouble, another way is to try making a function that does just stage one. Then, try making a function that does just stage two. Then, use those functions in your `dispRange` function.

Comment: How do I chop off the first x elements without using in-built functions?

Comment: @RyanThompson You can use pattern matching, like this: `chop n (x:xs) = …` (where `(x:xs)` is short for `x` is the first element of the list and `xs` are the rest of the elements of the list) for the recursive case and then only pass `xs` back to the function recursively, leaving `x` out of it. That chops off the first element of the list.

Comment: I wanted to combine these two functions, chopF, which displays the new list starting from the the 'Front index', chopF n (x:xs)
      | n == 0 = x:xs
      | otherwise = chopF (n-1) xs.

Comment: and chopB, trimming from the 'Back' index. chopB nl n (x:xs)
      | n == 0 = x:nl   
      | otherwise = chopB nl (n-1) xs. However I'm having a problem concatenating to the new list. any help?